# Dlookup reference where name of column being searched is the name of the textbox on my form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am editing a database created by my predecessor at work. I am creating a "helper" textbox that will pull a value from a table in the same database.

Problem is, in my Dlookup, the name of the column that I am searching is also the name of the textbox on my form that contains the criteria. To change the name of my textbox, I would have to update a lot of code that I did not create. Is there a way around this?

```
txtgreigeweight = Application.DLookup("[GreigeWeightAvg]", "dbo_TuftingGreigeData", "GreigeRoll# = GreigeRoll#")
```

I expect the output to be the "GreigeWeightAvg" value from the table.

The output is:

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'GreigeRoll# = GreigeRoll#'."

Comment: Your criteria needs to be concatenated to the string so that you pass the value instead of just the name of your text field -  try the criteria of the dlookup as “GreigeRoll# = “ & GreigeRoll#

Answer (score 0):

Try to *concatenate* the value:

```
txtgreigeweight = Application.DLookup("[GreigeWeightAvg]", "dbo_TuftingGreigeData", "[GreigeRoll#] = " & Me![GreigeRoll#].Value & "")
```

or, it text:

```
txtgreigeweight = Application.DLookup("[GreigeWeightAvg]", "dbo_TuftingGreigeData", "[GreigeRoll#] = '" & Me![GreigeRoll#].Value & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the fully-qualified control name in your selection criteria, e.g.:

```
txtgreigeweight = Application.DLookup("[GreigeWeightAvg]", "dbo_TuftingGreigeData", "GreigeRoll# = [Forms]![YourFormName]![GreigeRoll#]")
```

Change `YourFormName` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

At first stop using special characters in field Names...some might think that it improves readability..BUT it won't...its almost a recipe for issues.
So ... just clarify what kind of value is GreigeRoll#
If its numeric (like 1,21,21321) then you should have :

```
txtgreigeweight = DLookup("[GreigeWeightAvg]", "dbo_TuftingGreigeData", "GreigeRoll# =" &  [GreigeRoll#])
```

On the other hand is alphanumeric (like "A12", "BigGreige","1stG") then it should be :

```
txtgreigeweight = DLookup("[GreigeWeightAvg]", "dbo_TuftingGreigeData", "GreigeRoll# ='" &  [GreigeRoll#] & "'")
```